# Liskov Substitution Principle and PHP Interfaces

Tags: php, oop, covariance, contravariance, liskov-substitution-principle

Is the following code a direct violation of Liskov Substitution Principle:
 *Child classes should never break the parent class' type definitions.*

```php
class Baz {}
class Foo extends Baz {}

interface a
{
    public function baz(Baz $baz);
}

class b implements a
{
    public function baz(Foo $foo)
    {
    }
}
```

Which results on:

> **Fatal error**:  Declaration of b::baz(Foo $foo) must be compatible with a::baz(Baz $baz)

Comment: you are trying to input a subtype when you are specifically asking for Baz in the interface. Although Foo is a subtype of Baz it is still not the requested class.

Comment: @MHewison Isn't that the whole point? That should be possible, problem is that PHP doesn't support contravariance and/or covariance.

Comment: Yes, you're right it is not supported in PHP. As Method argument types in PHP are invariant. The interface must be adhered to as a minimum. In PHP you would usually create an interface which suits your implementation. So i guess, generally this is not a violation of LSP but in PHP it is not supported.

Comment: @MHewison Thank you. Then it seems that I don't fully understand LSP. For me, it looks like Foo as a subtype of Baz should be substitutable for Baz.
_Subtypes must be substitutable for their base types_  - Robert C. Martin

Comment: an implementation would be along the lines of ```interface a { } class A implements a {} class B implements a {}``` then ```class Bar { public function baz(a $implementation) {} }``` notice, the interface in place of where the parent type would be.

Comment: Isn't that Dependency Inversion Principle?
**Abstractions should not depend on details. Details should depend on abstractions**.
Or simply : Depend on Abstractions not on concretions.
Your example states that A or B are parents of a?

Comment: @Alex Objects of type `Foo` can be used instead of objects of type `Baz`. But your implemention of an interface should still be compatible with that interface, so that users of the class can base their expectation on the interface definition, not on the concrete implementation definition. See my answer for more details.

Comment: @yivi I see what you mean. If you have time please check out this article. I like where this discussion goes and thank you for your time.
https://devalmonte.com/blog/2019-04-18/interfaces-in-php-dont-make-complete-sense/

Comment: @yivi In the article, author is using the same approach. Using subtype in the interface implementation. And then demonstrating how this works just fine in C#. So, since PHP doesn't support contravariance and/or covariance, yet, and LSP is closely related to both contravariance and covariance I thought that LSP is violated.

Comment: Again, even when support for variance and contravariance is added to PHP 7.4, your example would be invalid for the reasons I explained in my answer.

Comment: This is from PHP documentation:  
`Note:
The class implementing the interface must use a method signatures which is compatible with LSP (Liskov Substitution Principle). Not doing so will result in a fatal error.`  
Class Foo, in my example, should work as it is a subtype of Baz.  
Or am I completely  not understanding this?

Answer (score 1):

The fact that your example is illegal doesn't break LSP. Your problem is that are defining an interface and expected to comply with that contract if implementing it.

It's important to remember is that in the end LSP deals with **objects**, not with **classes**.

By implementing interface `a` and then attempting to make the method signature not compatible, users of the class `b` could attempt calling `b::baz()` and fail because the signature of `a::baz()` expects a `Baz`, and your non-compatible implementation on `b::baz()` expects an instance `Foo`.

E.g., if what you propose were legal, this could happen:

```php
$baz = new Baz();

$b = new b();

// since a::baz(Baz) is specified, the class user believes this
// should be possible, but your illegal implementation
// breaks that expectation

$b->baz($baz); // Not accepted!
```

This doesn't break LSP at all.

A class that **properly** implements your interface `a` can still accept objects of classes `Foo` and `Baz`, **since objects of a sub-type can be used instead of those of the super-type**, exactly as LSP says.

What you can't do is write a method with a non-compatible signature, and future covariance and contravariance support won't allow for that either.

---

**Regarding covariance and contravariance support in return types and parameter types**: there is support incoming in PHP 7.4, due to be released at the end of 2019.

You can read about the details of the of the (accepted) proposal [here](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/covariant-returns-and-contravariant-parameters).

- Covariance will be supported only for return types (so that definitions can now specify subclasses of `T` if the parent class or interface declared a return type of `T`)
- Contravariance will be supported for parameters types (so that subclasses or implementing classes can now declare super-types of `T` as parameter type if the parent or interface declared a parameter type of `T`)

> When determining the compatibility of an method with its parent's the engine should now permit less specific parameter types and more specific return types as long as the new types still accept the types specified by the parents. In other words: a parameter type can be substituted for one of its super-types and a return type can substitute a sub-type.

This, again, will allow LSP support and allow for class users to be able to trust the abstractions they are programming against, instead of having to check the specifics of the concrete class they are using.

Comment: Here is a article published by Laravel news, which addresses the same problem.
https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:activity:6542838683446452224/
If the author is not wrong C# implementation of this works with no problem at all.
So, I am still skeptical about this answer.

Comment: It seems that this is know "issue".
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php#113793