# interface method with varying parameter type how to overcome "Declaration must be compatible with..." massage?

Tags: php, interface

```
interface IColoredParameter {
    //...
}

class RedParameter implements IColoredParameter
{
    //...
}
class GreenParameter implements IColoredParameter
{
    //...
}
interface IPaintable {
    public function paint(IColoredParameter $collored_parameter):void;
}

class GreenBox implements IPaintable {
    // Got an error here: Declaration must be compatible with IPaintable->paint(collored_parameter: \IColoredParameter) 
    public function paint(GreenParameter $collored_parameter):void
    {
    }
}
```

I have many classes that have a `paint` method but each method has a different parameter class. I want to add an interface to force `paint` method to be present
This approach works in C# but not in PHP.

What should I do in this case ?

Comment: Suggested reading [contravariance](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.variance.php), might help.

Comment: possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56609678/liskov-substitution-principle-and-php-interfaces)